# Problem when creating and executing stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I had created a stored procedure in MySQL. It has to get the values for 5 different columns and perform calculations based on the input params and update the calculated value to the table. I was able to create the stored procedure, but when executing it, it throws an error stating that 'MYSQL said: #1172 - Result consisted of more than one row.'

Below is my stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`andrew`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `st_update_userpoints`(
     in point int,
     in gold int,
     in silver int,
     in bronze int,
     in userId int)
BEGIN
     DECLARE _gold int default 0;
     DECLARE _silver int default 0;
     DECLARE _bronze int default 0;
     DECLARE _points int default 0;
     DECLARE _score int default 0;
     
     select `goldMedal`,`silverMedal`,`bronzeMedal`,`totalPoints`,`score` into @_gold,@_silver,@_bronze,@_points,@_score from `userpoints` where `userId`=userId;
     
     set _gold:=(@_gold+gold);
     set _silver:=(@_silver+silver);
     set _bronze:=(@_bronze+bronze);
     set _points:=(@_points+points);
     set _score = (@_gold*5)+(@_silver+3)+(@_bronze)+(@_points);
     
     update `userpoints` set `goldMedal`=@_gold, `silverMedal`=@_silver, `bronzeMedal`=@_bronze, `totalPoints`=@_points,
     `score`=@_score where `userId`=userId;
     END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The only statement I can see that can produce this error is: `select ... from `userpoints` where `userId`=userId;`. Are you sure this SQL query can only produce 1 row at most?

Comment: Yes. userId is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`` where `userId`=userId `` uses `in userId int` input parameter value for both left and right part. Hence it is always TRUE except the rows where `userpoints.userId` is NULL (and in this case the query returns multiple rows), and it is always NULL==FALSE if the provided parameter value is NULL (and the query does not return rows).

Use `where userpoints.userId=userId` - in this case the leftpart value is column value and the right part value is provided parameter value. And I'd check the provided value for NULL...

Answer (score 0):

Finally corrected stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `st_update_userpoints`(
     in points int,
     in gold int,
     in silver int,
     in bronze int,
     in userId int)
BEGIN
     DECLARE _gold int default 0;
     DECLARE _silver int default 0;
     DECLARE _bronze int default 0;
     DECLARE _points int default 0;
     DECLARE _score int default 0;
     
     select `goldMedal`,`silverMedal`,`bronzeMedal`,`totalPoints`,`score` into _gold,_silver,_bronze,_points,_score from `userpoints` where `userpoints`.`userId`=userId;
     
     set _gold:=(_gold+gold);
     set _silver:=(_silver+silver);
     set _bronze:=(_bronze+bronze);
     set _points:=(_points+points);
     set _score = (_gold*5)+(_silver*3)+(_bronze*1)+(_points);
     
     update `userpoints` set `goldMedal`=_gold, `silverMedal`=_silver, `bronzeMedal`=_bronze, `totalPoints`=_points,
     `score`=_score where `userpoints`.`userId`=userId;
     END $$
DELIMITER ;
```